# Maven does not copy non-java files

Tags: java, maven-2, maven

I have a pom.xml file with the following:

```
<sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/test</sourceDirectory>
<outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/bin </outputDirectory>
```

Inside `${basedir}/src/main/test` I have some folders which do not contain any .java files. When I start a compilation they are not copied to `${basedir}/src/main/bin` directory.

Only .java files are moved (after compilation of course) and stored on the right folder.

Can someone help me to solve this problem without using any plugin ?

I tried with

```xml
<resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
             <directory>${basedir}/src/main/test/scenarios</directory>
             <includes>
                <include>*.xml</include>
             </includes>
             <targetPath>${basedir}/src/main/bin/scenarios</targetPath>
        </resource>

        <resource>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
             <directory>${basedir}/src/main/test/sut</directory>
             <includes>
                <include>*.xml</include>
             </includes>
             <targetPath>${basedir}/src/main/bin/sut</targetPath>
        </resource>

    </resources>
```

But it does not work.  What is wrong?

Comment: Works for me with the above folder structure and code snippet.   Do you get any error?  Do the folders get created in `src/main/bin`?  Do you have `*.xml` contents in `src/main/test`?

Comment: I don't catch any error but I does not work, the directory target is created by the compile state, may this can be the main problem ?

Comment: `mvn compile` does not create target folder; `mvn package` or `mvn install` does.  What do you want to do after copying the contents to `src/main/bin`?  Should these get into the `jar`? If so you have more work to do customizing `maven jar plugin`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If they are not java files you should move them to the `src/main/resources` and/or `src/test/resources` directory. That's the maven convention for storing the non java files.

Your other option is to use the [maven-resources-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/).

```xml
  <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
        <directory>src/main/test</directory>
            <includes>
                <include> <the_files_you_want_to_include></include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

You have another option is to use the [maven-antrun-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) and execute an ant task to copy the files manually.

Comment: pedr0: Why exactly do you need to hold them there? Maven will copy them under the correct package name in the final artifact (jar/war). So if you are doing resource look up that should work fine.

Comment: My problem is that I have to work with JSystem which MUST have a particular folder structure.

Comment: pedr0: you should utilize the resources plugin in that case to manually include/exclude non java files copy.

Answer (score 1):

You can add src/main/test as a resource directory using the maven resources plugin.  see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html for basic information and http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html for information on only including certain files (since you won't want to copy your .java files)